# Can USB host ports be dangerous in uncontrolled environments? Virus etc?

Tags: usb-debugging, usb-host-mode

We have an Android device with 2 external USB host ports. Now I wonder what harm can be accomplished by an attacker with malicous intentions, provided that:

- The user can not access settings or any App that we do not control (love an example of apps we would need to prevent access to)
- USB debugging is turned off
- Our device is rooted (just to mention)

Could you give me an example what harm an attacker could do, considered the above conditions.

As I understand it, if a USB is mounted, then for something to be dangerous, it has to be executed. However execution must come from "the inside", no?
If we control the inside, then there shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Just saying, the chances of receiving high-quality answer are better on [security.se], for the topic in question here.